# Program returning values as NaN

Tags: javascript

Im trying to get this program to work and i have everything running, but my values return as NaN. I've tried initializing the variables as numbers both in and outside the function to no avail. Any help?

EDIT: added in the entire script, html and all incase it helps alongside the edits suggested thus far.

```
<html>
<head>

   <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
   <title>Placeholder</title>


</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Resturant Calculator</h1>
    </header>

    <article>
        <fieldset>
                <label for="bill">
                    Bill Amount
                </label>
                <input type="number" id="bill" />
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
                <label for="tip">
                    Tip Percent
                </label>
                <input type="number" id="tip" />
                <label>(enter as whole number)</label>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
                <label for="peeps">
                    # of people
                </label>
                <input type="number" id="peeps" />
        </fieldset>
        <button id="submit" onclcick="calculate()">Calculate</button>
        <p id="tipAmount">Tip Amount:</p>

        <p id="total">Total Bill:</p>
        <p id="totalByPeep">Total per Person:</p>
    </article>

   <script>
        "use strict"
        var bill = document.getElementById("bill").value;
        var tip = document.getElementById("tip").value;
        var peeps = document.getElementById("peeps").value;

        var total;
        var totalTip;
        var tpPerson;

        function calculate(){
            totalTip = bill.value / (tip.value * 0.01);
            total = bill.value + totalTip;
            tpPerson = total / peeps.value;

            document.getElementById("tipAmount").innerHTML = "Tip Amount: " + totalTip;
            document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = "Total: " + total;
            document.getElementById("totalByPeep").innerHTML = "Total per Person: " + tpPerson;
        }


        function createEventListener(){
            var submitButton = document.getElementById("submit");

            if (submitButton.addEventListener){
                submitButton.addEventListener("click", calculate, false);
            }
            else if(submitButton.attachEvent){
                submitButton.attachEvent("onclick", calculate);
            }

        }

        if (window.addEventListener){
            window.addEventListener("load", createEventListener, false);
        }
        else if (window.attachEvent){
            window.attachEvent("onload", createEventListener);
        }
</script>
   </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the values from the elements `bill`,`tip`,`peeps`
Probably something like `document.getElementById("bill").value`

Using just `document.getElementById("bill")` you are selecting the element, but not its value

Comment: That's right. And you will also need to convert those values into numbers, because input values are always strings. You can do that with "parseInt", "Number" or just a "+".e.g.: +document.getElementById("bill").value;

Comment: Yes I agree, it is recommended to convert it to number. The output will also depend from the operations you are performing. For example if you are using `+` is will concatenate the numbers with "string number".

Comment: i tried using ```+document.getElementById("bill").value;``` for each but they all returned NaN again. However, when used ```.value``` later in the ```calculate()``` function, it worked but the numbers are completely wrong.

Comment: Please share the complete code with us. You will need to get the values in `calculate()` everytime you want to to perform calculation.

Comment: Added everythig i have plus the edits, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the value inside `calculate()`

```
    function calculate(){
        bill = +bill.value, tip = +tip.value, peeps = +peeps.value;
        totalTip = bill/ (tip * 0.01);
        total = bill + totalTip;
        tpPerson = total / peeps;

        document.getElementById("tipAmount").innerHTML = "Tip Amount: " + totalTip;
        document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = "Total: " + total;
        document.getElementById("totalByPeep").innerHTML = "Total per Person: " + +tpPerson;
    }
```